# Trend break in panel data

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, trend, structural-change

I have a panel of countries (N= 30) over four decades (T= 40). I would like to test the impact of a policy by analyzing whether it led to a change in the trend in the outcome variable. Note: The policy was implemented at different times in different countries.

I am currently running the following regression but fear it is the wrong one as it is not looking at breaks within each country:
   `y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Policy_{it} + \beta_2 Policy_{it} x t + e_{it}`
where `y_{it}` is the outcome of interest in country `i` at time `t`; `Policy_{it}` is 1 for all years policy is in force and 0 otherwise; `t` is a linear time trend; and `e_{it}` is the error term. I have the following questions:

1) Is there a way to test for a single trend break in a panel data, or should I be estimating the above regression for each country separately?

2) If I am to exploit the panel structure of the data, should I also include year FE?

3) I am also concerned that since my N is small and T is large the regular panel data asymptotics may not apply. Am I correct in thinking this way?

Please provide any other advice you may have.